# Dropzone.JS in form with Laravel 5.2 not saving file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

enctype="multipart/form-data" been stuck on this issue with saving the uploaded file to the Database using DropzoneJS.

The error in this case is that it's posting all the other form data except for the uploaded file which returns an empty response although I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

If anyone can manage to spot the error, it would be greatly appreciated!

View

```
<form action="{{url('/save_information')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}" />
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="form-group">
    <legend></legend>
</div>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control">

<label for="description">Description</label>
<input type="text" name="description" id="input-description" class="form-control">

<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone",{
            url: "/save_information",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 10, // MB
            sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            }
        });


        $('#submit-all').click(function(){
            e.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
```

controller function

```
 if (Request::hasFile('filename')) {
        $image = Request::file('filename');
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($location, $filename);

            $trustDocument->image = $filename;

        } else {
        dd('no image found');
    }

$trustDocument->save();
```

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

The paramName you set is "file" but in your controller you are referencing to "filename".

> Replace "filename" to "file" in your controller.

For more detailed integration with laravel dropzone you can refer to this tutorial [Integrating Dropzone.js in Laravel 5 applications](http://anytch.com/integrating-dropzone-js-laravel-5-applications/)